# ios crash on EXRunningExtension resume

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I'm seeing multiple crashes in my app coming from `ExtensionFoundation : [_EXRunningExtension resume]`.
I'm using widgets inside my app, so that's probably related, but there is no specific code to my app as the stack takes 5 lines.

How can I find the cause for this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: @Barrrdi I did not unfortunately

Comment: Looks like this exception is just a "cover up" exception and the real issue is hidden on other threads. I suggest opening the crash in xcode project and taking a look at them.